# general definition of combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, definition

I was looking for a general definition of combinatorial problems, and i found this definition :
A combinatorial problem is defined by a couple (S,C) associated with a request R, where :

- S is a **finite or infinite** set of potential solutions.
- C is a **finite** set of properties to be satisfied.
- R is a request specifying the objective of the resolution.

The author used these ingredients to define, after, a combinatorial optimization problem.

From what I know, a combinatorial problem is characterized by a finite set of feasible solutions.

My question is how this definition can be true by saying that S is infinite? and why C should be finite? Need some deeper explanations, please!

Regards

Comment: When you think about this definition: what kind of problem does *not* fall under this category? It seems to me a little unspecific. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Like problems modeled by continuous linear programming, where the variables are defined in R, here we have an infinite set of solutions, a combinatorial problem is characterized by discrete variables, and thus, the search space is finite. we can say countably infinite, but infinite alone is a little hard to be accepted.